# “Reject and edit” on tag wiki excerpt does not show the current content

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

On a [suggested edit review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/160228) for a [tag wiki excerpt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modem), I clicked “Reject and Edit”. I expected to be brought to an edit box with the previous content of the excerpt, but instead I got an empty edit box.

I do have the [privilege to edit tag wikis without supervision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). The excerpt was non-empty before the suggested edit. There was no content in the tag wiki body, if it matters.

Generally, on suggested edits to posts and tag wikis (not excerpts), the editing form pre-fills with the content of the pre-suggested-edit version. However, this seems broken for tag wiki *excerpts*.

Comment: This is still an issue today.